In Flutter, is there a way to change the input colour of a showDatePicker
When creating a DatePicker, it uses the theme of my overall project. Throughout the rest of my project, the text colour for an input is white. When using the DatePicker, I can pick a date (duh) or I can manually enter a date. It's this input of manually entering a date where I want to change the colour of the input specifically for this input (i.e, without messing around with the theming of the entire app). Am I missing a property on my DatePickerTheme?
This is my code:
final inputDecorationTheme = InputDecorationTheme(
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 14),
  filled: true,
  fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
  hintStyle: textTheme.labelMedium!.apply(color: Palette.darkGrey),
  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
  labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Palette.border, width: 1)),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Palette.border, width: 1)),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Palette.border, width: 1)),
  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Palette.error, width: 1)),
);

final datePickerTheme = DatePickerThemeData(
  cancelButtonStyle: TextButton.styleFrom(
    foregroundColor: Colors.black, // Color for text on buttons
  ),
  confirmButtonStyle: TextButton.styleFrom(
    foregroundColor: Palette.primary, // Color for text on buttons
  ),
  inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationTheme,
);


I have tried altering the InputDecorationTheme (as I suspect this is sort of where it is?)
I am a junior, so I probably haven't tried many (any) abstract ideas here.

Please provide an image of what is happening with the current code to better understand what you intend to do. Thanks.

@Priyaank hi, thanks for commenting. Here is what is looks like. As you can see, the text is white when ideally it would be at least readable haha. https://imgur.com/a/cQpVsUz

Can you try this!
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 365)),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365)),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(onPrimary: kWhite, onBackground: kWhite),
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
          headerBackgroundColor: kPrimary,
          backgroundColor: kWhite,
          headerForegroundColor: kWhite,
          surfaceTintColor: kWhite,
        ),
      ),
      child: child!,
    );
  },
);


Hey! Nice try, unfortunately didn't work. That changes the overall theme of the actual date picker, but doesn't change the input text colour (as can be seen here) https://imgur.com/a/cQpVsUz
